# The statement callback raised an exception or statement error callback did not return false

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, jaydata

I'm getting this error:

> SQLError 
>   {
>     code: 0,
>     message: "the statement callback raised an exception or statement error callback did not return false"`  }

When running a Cordova program (which uses JayData).

What does this error mean? what causes it? What should I look at to fix it?

Comment: where is your code that caused the error? which query did you run? Whats the layout/contents of the database you are trying to pull?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets - excellent questions but unfortunately I don't have the answers - it is a very large system and I can see the error but don't have any details as to it's source - this is why I've asked this very general question.